# twitter bootstrap at 1180 pixels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and need it to be 1180 pixels wide and not 980 as ships by default. I have manually changed the css such that all .span, .offset and .container elements go in multiplies of 80 instead of 60. So far this looks good. Is this approach going to bite me anytime?

BTW
1. I know about the responsive bootstrap option but it makes my site look bad on ipads.
2. Also couldn't do it from less since got strange results.

Comment: What sort of "strange results" were you getting with LESS? There are variables provided in variables.less specifically for the purpose you've described.

Comment: I'm on 2.0.4 and the latest version is 2.1.1. I tried less from that version, which might be the reason why my site broke (though minor version should not break things). But even with less I want to know if I'm done after changing that one var or is there a bigger limitation for wide resolution.

Comment: While there were some fairly significant changes in 2.0.4 -> 2.1.1, it's likely that the "breakage" was caused by overwriting your modifications to the Bootstrap core.  
That's why it's preferable to use LESS - changing one or two LESS variables is far easier to maintain than combing through hundreds of lines of CSS every time you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

This might bite you if you want to update by simply using git. A better way might be to use this [Bootstrap customization site](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html)

If you can't use LESS and you are sure your calculations are correct then I would just put my custom CSS in a seperate stylesheet included after bootstrap.css, but before bootstrap-responsive.css. That way the custom file will override the defaults css, and you don't have to edit bootstrap itself.

You won't have to dig through bootstrap to make your own edits and you can update bootstrap painlessly.

Comment: thanks but I'm on 2.0.4 and this site has 2.1.1 which for some reason breaks my site

Comment: Well if you can't use LESS and you are sure your calculations are correct then I would just put your custom CSS in a seperate stylesheet included after bootstrap.css. That way your file will override the defaults, but you don't have to edit bootstrap itself.